# localStorage & sessionStorage are undefined running debugger on IE 11 and Edge

Tags: javascript

```
   if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("Hello", "somedata");
        alert(localStorage.getItem("Hello"));
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    }
```

Using IE 11 debugger, Storage is [object Storage] but localStorage is undefined and the above will give an error "Unable to get property 'setItem' of undefined or null reference"

Using FireFox debugger, Storage is function() and localStorage and sessionStorage are Storage. localStorage and sessionStorage work correctly on Firefox.
Why isn't Microsoft supporting the localStorage and sessionStorage correctly?